# Weka - load UTF-8 encoded csv

Tags: java, utf-8, weka

Is there a way in Weka 3.7.13 to load UTF-8 encoded files without converting them to ANSII?

I am trying to load a csv file containing a string attribute, whose value can contain emoticons, and I need not to lose them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very possible to do this. See this [link](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Can+I+process+UTF-8+datasets+or+files%3F), it describes how to do this from command line or GUI.

Add this parameter if using the command line `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8`.

If using the GUI then edit the `RunWEKA.ini` file. Change the `fileEncoding` placeholder to `utf-8`.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me using the GUI. How about solving the same problem from Java code? `Instances a = new DataSource(filePath).getDataSet()` keeps throwing exception.

Comment: Can you tell me the exception it throws? As long as the file is saved with UTF-8 encoding java should read it like that. Otherwise, I suggest using XRFF instead of ARFF as it allows for explicit declaration of encoding.

Comment: It was same error it throws from the GUI (it is related to how utf-8 charachter are read in ANSI). I solved this problem: as you said, java reads the file like UTF-8, in fact the problem was the codification of my Eclipse project, which read the csv with ANSI

Comment: I edited your answer for completeness, in case someone has the same problem (which, in the end, was a dumb problem)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, if you are using weka programmatically, you need to change your `IDE`'s encoding to `utf-8` in order to handle `utf-8` encoded data.